# Java lambdas: replace -> operator with :: for stream filter

Tags: java, lambda, operators

There is an event class:

```
public class Event {
    private int index;
    public int getIndex() {return index;}
}
```

Also there is a method - it selects an event sublist with certain values of "index" property. Extremely simple, but such functionality is widely used.

```
public List<Event> select(List<Event> scenario, List<Integer> indexesToInclude) {
    Predicate<Event> indexMatcher = e -> indexesToInclude.contains(e.getIndex());
    return scenario.stream().filter(indexMatcher).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The task is to avoid usage of -> operator in favor of :: operator. Why? Because *e -> ...* looks like a workaround for such common task.

Is it possible to do?
I expect syntax like (this won't compile of course):

```
Predicate<Event> indexMatcher = { indexesToInclude.contains(Event::getIndex) };
```

however it can be a chain of methods or other solution without writing loops or creating new classes/methods.

Comment: *"Because `->` looks like a workaround"*???? It's anything but a workaround. It's the entire point of the **new a very powerful feature** added to Java 8, called *lambda expressions*. They didn't do through all that work for a "workaround"!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do?

No.  Lambda expressions (the so-called "workaround") are the way to do this.  That's what they were added to the language for.

<sup>(Actually ... you *could* do this the old-school way by defining an anonymous inner class.  But it won't be a one-liner.)</sup>

---

> Why? Because `e -> ...` looks like a workaround for such common task.

I guess, it depends on your perspective.  For instance, a syntax purist might consider `s1 + i` as a "workaround" for `s1.concat(Integer.toString(i))`.

In fact, these things are generally called "syntactic sugar" ... and they are added to a language *to make it easier* to write concise and readable code.

Obviously, to be able to read the code you first need to understand the syntax, then you need to get used to it.

Unfortunately, it seems that the real problem here seems to be that you don't *like* the Java lambda syntax.  Sorry, but you will just need to get used to it.  Fighting it is not going to work.